# How to send multiple large files via http request С#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am writing an analogue of a messenger in which I am trying to attach files to a message. I put all the files in an ObservableCollection, then I create a MultipartFormDataContent and add all the files there, set the correct headers and send the files.
My code

```
 private  void _SendFile(string ShortUrl,  ObservableCollection<LastFilesModel> files)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = IpAddress_server + ShortUrl;
               
                client = new HttpClient();
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
                content.Headers.Add(@"Content-Length", "2147483648");
                int count = 0;
                foreach(var file in files)
                {
                    count++;
                    var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(file.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file_"+ count, file.ShortName);
                    
                }
              
                
               
                var httpMethod = HttpMethod.Post;

                
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                    Method = httpMethod,
                    Content = content,
                    
                 
                };
          
             
                
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + MyUser.Token);
                
                var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var s =ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

If I send 1 file then everything is fine or several small ones, but as soon as I send a large file, for example 33 mb, then the following error occurs.

```
One or more errors occurred. (contentLength < 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server `(nginx)` set the maximum amount of files to be uploaded and removed the `ContentLengtn` headers

Dlete code

```
content.Headers.Add(@"Content-Length", "2147483648");
stream.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTTP server is not configured to accept files over a certain size.  You'll have to reconfigure it.  You didn't specify the server type, so from here you're on you own as to how to solve this problem.

Comment: I set the size of the files on the server:
-upload max file size
-post max size
And what does the server type mean? server address correct answers come from it!!